# Automatically describe structure of SSIS-package

Tags: xml, ssis, documentation-generation, catalog

Is there a way to generate a document that contains all objects in a SSIS-package with the constraints between them?

What I am looking for is a description like:

1. **Name**: [Name of Task] **Type**: [Type of Task] **Description**: [Description of Task]
2. **Constraint**: [Type of Constraint] **Condition**: [Condition of Constraint]
3. **Name**: [Name of Task] **Type**: [Type of Task] **Description**: [Description of Task]
4. ...

Having this on Control Flow level would already be enough. It seems to me that this information is available in the Catalog as well as in the .dtsx files in the shape of XML. It follows that it must be possible to extract this information for use in for example a word document.

Are there any freeware tools available that can/would do this? Or could anyone point me in the right direction for extracting this information from the Catalog?